# array_combine receiving a boolean but data says otherwise

Tags: php, arrays

So I have written the function below to parse a CSV file and then pass it back to the controller.

The problem is the array_combine function is receiving false as the second argument however when I print out the second argument I get an an array of data as expected..

```
public function parseData($meta, $filename = 'file.csv')
{
    $fileContents = fopen($meta . $filename, 'r');
    $result = fgetcsv($fileContents, 1000, "\t", "\n");

    $allRowResult = array();
    while (!feof($fileContents)) {
        $rows[] = fgetcsv($fileContents, 1000, "\t", "\n");
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

        $newArray = array_combine($result, $row);
        array_push($allRowResult, $newArray);


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($row);
        echo "</pre>";


        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    return $allRowResult;

}
```

print_r($row) returns

```
Array
(
[0] => BBB
[1] => 10000001
[2] => 10000001
[3] => 06/15/2015
[4] => 07/06/2015
[5] => $0.00
[6] => $0.00
[7] => $40.14
[8] => $40.14
[9] => First Last
[10] => 123 Street
[11] => NULL
[12] => City
[13] => Province
[14] => Postal
[15] => 
[16] => P
[17] => 
[18] => filename.pdf
[19] => filename
[20] => 
[21] => 
[22] => 
[23] => 
[24] => 
[25] => 
[26] => 
[27] => 
[28] => 
[29] => 
[30] => 
[31] => 0
[32] => 1
[33] => 3
[34] => 1
[35] => 3
[36] => 11312
[37] => 5649
```

)

Comment: Have you got an example of the csv file you are reading

Comment: It's internal data but its a very typical CSV. Nothing crazy.

Comment: check that fgetcsv isn't stuffing a boolean FALSE into your $rows. when you foreach on $rows, you'll be trying to treat that false as an array, causing array_combine to faile in that one instance.

Answer (score 0):

array_combine takes an array as the second parameter, and $row is not an array.

[definition of array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

> array array_combine ( array $keys , array $values )

Comment: In this context, $row is an array. The both print_r and var_dump determine $row is an array.

Comment: so print_r($rows) returns Array ?

Comment: Yes. Corrected my first comment.

Comment: can you post a screenshot or print out of your print_r($row) ... because fgetcsv returns an array (not an array of arrays)

Comment: Updated question with the result of print_r

Comment: try: while($rows = fgetcsv($fileContents, 1000, "\t", "\n") !== FALSE) {
            $newArray = array_combine($result, $rows);
            array_push($allRowResult, $newArray);
        }

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up swapping out my while loop for this

```
while(($line = fgetcsv($fileContents,1000,"\t", "\n")) !== FALSE){
       $rows[] = $line;
    }
```

Sorted the issue right out.